# Can't input traditional Chinese words in AutoCompleteTextField by Google Gboard keyboard on Samsung

Tags: codenameone

On my Samsung mobile phone, there is no other language option in Language settings except for "English", also Gboard keyboard settings don't show the "Traditional Chinese" language option on AutoCompleteTextField.
But TextField and TextArea components don't have this "Traditional Chinese" problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details on how the problem manifests? 
Screenshots? UX behavior etc?

Comment: I have some screenshots attached to the question.
Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going on. I don't see the popup in both cases. Do you start typing? Are there physically CJK characters in the field that should match at that point?

Does getText() return a value you can use to narrow down the list?